# how can I convert user textbox input into an integer?

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, int, type-conversion

I am trying to make a home brew calculator where when the user types in the original gravity and final gravity and presses the `Calculate` button the program use the data to calculate the alcohol by weight and alcohol by volume.

It seems simple but I am having difficulty converting the user input into integers that I can use for the equations. I am getting an error that reads

> the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable a property or
>   an indexer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BrowerD_Final
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declare variables
            int origGrav;
            int finalGrav;
            int gravDifference;
            int abw;
            int abv;

            //converting tbOrigGrav input to int
            origGrav = Convert.ToInt32(tbOrigGrav.Text);
            origGrav = int.Parse(tbOrigGrav.Text);

            //converting tbFinalGrav input to int
            finalGrav = Convert.ToInt32(tbFinalGrav.Text);
            finalGrav = int.Parse(tbFinalGrav.Text);

            //show numbers in messagebox for testing
            //MessageBox.Show(this.tbOrigGrav.Text);
            //MessageBox.Show(this.tbFinalGrav.Text);

            origGrav - finalGrav = gravDifference;

            gravDifference * 105 = abw;

            abw * 1.25 = abv;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

These assignments should be otherway like this

```
gravDifference = origGrav - finalGrav;
abw = gravDifference * 105 ;
abv = abw * 1.25 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in these lines:

```
origGrav - finalGrav = gravDifference;
gravDifference * 105 = abw;
abw * 1.25 = abv;
```

I think what you really mean to do is:

```
gravDifference = origGrav - finalGrav;
abw = gravDifference * 105;
abv = abw * 1.25;
```

BTW abv should probably be a floating point type rather than int, as it will get truncated / rounded

Also, your code isn't that robust, you probably want to check that there is valid input in the textbox in the first place, and then use `int.TryParse` rather than `Convert`